# Rancher API call with environment API key to call console app container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-machine, rancher

I have a requirement to call a container from Rancher UI using environment API key.

Here's my situation:

I have a .NetCore 2.0 console application with a test project(c# library)
Once I build my console application with the test project, I've deployed all dll's to a Unix server from which I build my image and container using Docker.

I am using rancher for front-end apps mgmt and setup all the necessary variables. my container is running fine and the project is doing what it's supposed to do.

I have to make the whole project automated like windows task scheduler which can run every 5 mins if setup correctly, I would like to call the Main.cs every 5mins but in my case, I have to use  http://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v1.6/en/api/v2-beta/  and call the Main.cs.

I have created environment API key which can use to call the API and need to figure out how to make that call.

any help will be greatly appreciated!